# Print do resultado de um operador ternário

Tags: python, operadores

Como mostrar o output de uma operação ternária junto à uma string, usando o Python?

Pretendo verificar se o tamanho do nome digitado é maior do que "Braga". Para esta condição, quero utilizar o operador ternário do Python para verificar se é "maior" ou "menor" e unir esta informação na string do print final: "O seu nome é maior/ menor que o meu!".

```
def operadorTernario():
  """ Exemplo do operador ternário """

  nome = input('Qual o seu nome? ')
  print('O seu nome é', 'maior' if len(nome) > 'Braga' else 'menor', 'que o meu!')


operadorTernario()
```

Para testar online, recomendo: [Repl.it](https://repl.it/)

Comment: "Maior que Braga" não faz sentido. Seria maior que o tamanho de Braga? Se sim, deveria ser `len('Braga')`, ou apenas 5 mesmo, visto que esse valor não iria mudar.

Comment: exatamente, como o @AndersonCarlosWoss você está comparando o tamanho do nome digitado com a palavra braga...

Comment: seria um if e else comum, caso for maior print maior que, caso menor print menor que

Comment: Lucas, você pode utilizar o botão *share* do Repl.it para compartilhar o seu código funcionando.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss me refiro ao tamanho de "Braga". Entendi o que de fato mostrava a saída de erro no terminal. Erroneamente eu estava retornando um `int` do nome recebido no input e tentando comparar com a string "Braga". Já consertei utilizando o `len('Braga') ` . Agradeço!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao fazer `len(nome) > 'Braga'` você estará comparando um número inteiro, que será retornado pela função `len`, com uma *string*. Isso não faz o menor sentido, inclusive dá o erro de tipo dizendo que a comparação entre *int* e *string* não é permitida.

O correto seria comparar dois valores inteiros, sendo o segundo obtido por `len('Braga')`:

```
'maior' if len(nome) > len('Braga') else 'menor'
```

Ou apenas 5, visto que o valor é constante:

```
'maior' if len(nome) > 5 else 'menor'
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ForkedInsidiousBasenji)</sup>

Vale notar que a comparação entre duas *strings* também é válida, porém não produz o resultado desejado. Ao comparar *strings*, você verifica a ordem alfabética das mesmas, determinando a posição relativa entre as duas; isto é, fazer `'anderson' < 'lucas'` é verdadeiro, pois 'a' vem antes do 'l', indiferente se a quantidade de caractere é maior ou menor. Se desejas comparar o tamanho, utilize `len`.

Comment: ótima resposta.

Comment: Perfeito Anderson!

Answer (score 0):

Você está fazendo a comparação com o próprio nome da pessoa que digitou, deveria colocar desta forma, como irei mostrar abaixo, afinal você tem de comparar a `string` digitada com um valor `string`

```
print('O seu nome é', 'maior' if (len(nome) > len('Braga')) else 'menor', 'que o meu!');
```

Também pode informar que o nome informado é `if len(nome) > 5` afinal a palavra Braga possui 5 caracteres, mas ai vai da sua necessidade

Comment: perdão não tinha reparado a desatenção, Já consertei